# Should I stop send push notification when another device foreground?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to show notification only app is close or background or in different chatroom. but I don't know which is better Solution.

1. stop send push notification when another device foreground
2. just send push notification anyway and don't show the notification in another device when app foreground.

In first solution I need to get another device information from server like in which chatroom or in which activity or in foreground it make my app and database more complex but maybe it reduce the network usage.

In second solution just send notification anyway and receiver device just ignore it but maybe big network usage.

Comment: If you are interested, I have exaplained in one of my tutorials step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** using Cloud Firestore and Node.js. In that example you will receive notifications only when the app is in background.

Comment: I send notifications use cloud function before.but when user increase.it cost too much. so i use own server now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most apps that I know off use the second approach: they always send the FCM message, and only show it when needed. That also means that they usually only send a so-called *tickle* message, which contains very little data and whose main purpose it is to wake the app up.